# Error Trying to fsync a Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to `fsync` a directory, to ensure that rename operation occurs. The problem that I'm having is that Python keeps returning a permission error, even though I have full permissions for the various folders I've tried this on.

```
directory = r'C:\Random\Path'
os.access(directory, os.W_OK)
os.access(directory, os.X_OK)
os.access(directory, os.R_OK)
True, True, True

fd = open(directory)
os.fsync(fd)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Random\\Path'
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there something deeper going on?

Comment: Perhaps a problem with permissions of `c:\Random`? I assume that you need write and/or execute rights on the parent directory to rename.

Comment: Does Windows allow you to `fsync()` directories in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in open() is not the same as os.open().  os.open() returns a file descriptor (an integer), but open() does not.  os.open() can open directories (at least on Linux it can, I haven't tried Windows), but open() cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The `fsync()` call is not being executed.  The error is coming from the `open()`.  Why?  Because you cannot open a directory on Windows.*

This behavior is [documented in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx):

> **EACCES**
>
> > Tried to open a read-only file for writing, file's sharing mode does not allow the specified operations, **or the given path is a directory.**

(emphasis mine).  `EACCES` is permission denied; it is being (ab)used as a general-purpose "you can't do that" error for [compatibility reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/01/17/354399.aspx).

---

* Specifically, you can't open a directory using the POSIX subsystem; it is possible to open a directory on Windows with [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx), but that gives you a handle which cannot be passed to [`FlushFileBuffers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) according to [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365258(v=vs.85).aspx), so this is still impossible.